# formatting clob data using select statment

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Suppose I have clob data as

```
abc,def,ghi|jkl
```

I need to put this in to another table as

```
col1        col2
abc,def,ghi jkl
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://lalitkumarb.com/2014/12/02/split-comma-delimited-string-into-rows-in-oracle/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SUBSTR` to get part of the string, `INSTR` to find the delimiter AND `LENGTH` to get the right size like below:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(CLOB,0,INSTR(CLOB,'|',0,1)) AS COL1
       ,SUBSTR(CLOB,INSTR(CLOB,'|',0,1),LENGTH(CLOB)-INSTR(CLOB,'|',0,1)) AS COL2, 
FROM DUAL
```